# Cryptic Division 5: Devil Magic

Tags: cryptic-clues, alphametic, printers-devilry

This is a [word division puzzle](https://www.pennydellpuzzles.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/How-to-Solve-Word-Math.pdf) which uses cryp- actually, this one uses [printer's devilry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer%27s_Devilry). If you're unfamiliar with either or both of those, you can click the associated link.

In order to solve the alphametic, you'll first need to fill in the dividend, divisor, and quotient  by solving the cryptic clues. I've left the enumerations off to provide a bit of extra challenge. Once you fill those in, the puzzle should be solvable with only arithmetic and logic. The solution is a 10-letter word or phrase found by ordering the letters from 0 through 9. A complete answer should provide this solution along with explanations of the cryptic clues and your path through the alphametic.

As always, I've created an [interactive version](https://codepen.io/juicifer/full/BavXQOK) that will autofill from the grid to the clues and vice versa. Have fun!

Clues:

> Can you bring so memo ream moon the hung trip next month? We didn't have enough today
> Listening to the song - so faint! - the same experience as seeing it performed on stage
> US Navy SEAL's shoto, Sam, a bin Last Ern, Pakistan, the location of his base

As mentioned, these are printer's devilry clues, and I've included an additional definition at either the start or end of the clue.

[image]

Accessible version:

```
         ???
     -------
????|???????
     ALDSE
     -----
      LDWNN
      LWNEW
      -----
       TLYNE
       LYWYL
        ----
        TEES
```

Comment: @Stevo try checking out the second link in my first paragraph above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the clues:

> "Can you bring so memo ream moon the hung trip next month? We didn't have enough today" becomes "**Can** you bring some more ammo on the hun**TIN**g trip next month? We didn't have enough today".

> "Listening to the song - so faint! - the same experience as seeing it performed on stage" becomes "Listening to the songs of ai**DA IS**n't the same experience as seeing it performed on **stage**"

> "US Navy SEAL's shoto, Sam, a bin Last Ern, Pakistan, the location of his base" becomes "US Navy SEAL's shot Osama bin L**ADEN IN E**astern, Pakistan, the location of his **base**"

As you can see, the clues hint at  the words to use in the division like so:

> CAN is synonym with TIN, STAGE with DAIS, and ADENINE is a BASE.

Now onto the division itself:

> We start with this grid:
>  [image]
>  I'll call {S1}, {S2} and {S3} the three substractions that are part of the division.

> W must be 0 as N-W=N in {S2}. Grid becomes:
>  [image]

Some other deductions:

> Per {S2}, T + 1 = D. Per {S3}, E + 1 = Y. Per {S1}, S + 1 = N. Per {S3}, L + 1 = T. Combining, L + 2 = D. As L + L = D per [S1}, L must be 2, then T is 3, then D is 4. Grid becomes this:
>  [image]

Let's continue:

> E must be 8 because E= 4+4 with no carry due to the 0 next to the bottom 4 (in {S1}). Y must then be 9. Grid becomes:
>  [image]

From here we can almost see what the name on top will be, but let's continue with the deductions:

> S must be 6 because of the last part in {S3}. Then N must be 7. Grid is now:
>  [image]

The last part:

> 7+8=15 so I is 5 ({S1}) leaving A with only 1 as a valid value. The resulting grid is as follows.
>  [image]

And of course, the final clue is none other than:

> Walt Disney!

Comment: sorry for the delay; I thought I had accepted this yesterday but apparently not. regardless, nice job on the solve!